# Multiple command line in unix

Tags: java, shell, command

> If you have installed java in your computer, you can get:

```
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

> after you enter the command
>   `java -version`

Here is the question how I can get the response three times with one line command?

I have tried the following:

`java -version java -version java -verision` (got once response)

`java -version \n java -version \n java -verision \n` (once response too)

`echo -e "java -version\njava -version\njava -verision\n"` (got jave -version three times in three line)

Comment: `;` is the sequential separator

Comment: `j(){ java -version; };j;j;j`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly:

```
java -version; java -version; java -version
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for a `for` loop:

```
for i in {1..3}; do java -version; done
```

`{1..3}` is a `bash` command that expands to `1 2 3`. If you use another shell, you can replace it with `$(seq 1 3)`

Answer (score 0):

use this command to chain multiple commands in a single line

```
java -version && java -version && java -version
```